# How to calculate average volume of a molecule?

Tags: molecules, mole

The molecular weight of glucose-1-phosphate is $\pu{260 g/mol}$ and its density is $\pu{1.5 g/mL}$. What is the average volume occupied by 1 molecule of this compound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Volume occupied by a single molecule can be roughly estimated as follows:

$$V_x = \frac{V_\mathrm m}{N_\mathrm A} = \frac{M}{\rho N_\mathrm A} = \frac{\pu{260 g mol^-1}}{(\pu{1.5 g ml^-1})(\pu{6.02E23 mol^-1})} \approx \pu{2.9E-22 ml},$$

where $V_\mathrm m$ is the molar volume, $M$ is the molar mass, $\rho$ is the density, and $N_\mathrm A$ is the Avogadro constant.

Note that "*volume occupied by a molecule*" and "*volume of a molecule*" are two separate entities.